# How to save date into 24 hours format in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am new to Oracle, and I need to save date and time in an Oracle database.

I am using time stamp as datatype for row. But now my problem is it saves date and time in 12 hours format like this `17/11/2011 10:10:10 PM`.

But I need it in 24 hours format like `17/11/2011 22:10:10`. I didn't understand the results that Google search result provided. Can any one please help me by posting some code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Oracle always stores timestamps (and dates) in a packed binary format that is not human readable.  Formatting is done only when a timestamp (or a date) is converted to a string.

You can control the formatting of your output by coding an explicit `to_char`.  For example

```
SELECT to_char( your_timestamp_column, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ) 
  FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 6):

Oracle stores timestamps in an internal format (with a default representation).

You can customize this representation on output like with the [`to_char()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm) function.

For input (into the database) you can use [`to_date()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm).

Comment: Good answer, however you can improve it by giving examples, especially to cater for the OP's requirements.